# How to get facebook friend count and post count?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried with graph api explorer to get user count. It work perfectly.

But how to get the total post count using API.

Is there any way to get the user count and post count of a a user using userId?

Answer (score 1):

There is no field or endpoint to get a user’s post count.

---

(Getting the user’s permission to read their posts, and then paginate through all of them & do the count yourself, might sound possible in theory, but in reality that probably won’t work. You’ll run into the API request limits quickly, plus there’s likely always gonna be some posts your app can’t “see” because of some obscure constellation of privacy settings. Also, from my experience, the API tends to get kinda unreliable, the further you try to go back in time.)

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to get the user count using user id?

Because in my project i have some users. So I just want to get the count of their users and posts.

Is there any way to get it without the syncing their facebook to my project?

Comment: I don’t even understand what you actually mean by that - _“to get the user count using user id”_ …? The “count” of the user with id X would be … well, _one_, because the user id is unique to begin with. Or are you actually talking about the count of _friends_ again now?

Comment: No. I just want the friends count and post count of each users that signup on my project.

Comment: `me/friends` gets you a `summary` property with `total_count` inside of it, provided the user granted `user_friends` permission.

Comment: it's right. But is there any to get count of another user using user id instead of me?

Comment: No. You can get almost _no_ data about any users that did not log in to your app and grant it permission any more these days, for privacy reasons.